# CSS - Does there exist an opposite of “:inherit”

Tags: css

Is there an opposite of `:inherit` in CSS? (If you are not familiar with `:inherit`: [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit))

E.g. to get an element to take over the width of its child, instead of its parent (the latter would be done using `:inherit`?

Comment: see display inline-block, inline-table , table and flex behavior, but inherit css from child doesn't exist

Comment: Such a feature wouldn't make sense since an element can have an arbitrary number of children.

Comment: @Sildoreth - That's true of course. It would be nice to be able to integrate something like the `:nth-child()` selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, CSS was designed so that inheritance works only so that an element may inherit from its parent.

The width of an element may depend on the widths of its children, but that’s an entirely different issue. In some contexts, an element takes the minimum width needed to accommodate its children. But that’s because it has been defined so; there is no magic word to use to achieve it in a manner comparable to the effect of the keyword `inherit`.